# How to replace an existing record of a core data entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I currently update the existing record of an entity by updating each key value of that record.

```
if(existingObjects != nil && existingObjects.count > 0){
            SomeEntity *anObject = [existingObjects objectAtIndex:0];

            anObject.key1 = @"Some value";
            anObject.key2 = @"Some value";
            anObject.key3 = @"Some value";
```

My question: Is there a way to completely replace/override a record of a core data entity rather than updating each value of that particular record?

Comment: If you have an object with the correct values, including relationships, you can delete the original and insert the new one.  I am not sure it's a good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the entity to replace and you have also the newer updated entity then all you need to do is to replace the entity and save the context,

```
if(existingTopics != nil && existingTopics.count > 0){
[existingTopics replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:entityUpdated];
}
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
[context deleteObject:entity];
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Replace 'entity' by 'object'. Please don't mix them up.

Comment: you were welcome to update text rather than downvoting @Willeke